# Javascript array-matching beginner

Tags: javascript, beginner

As a beginner coder in js, I'd like to hear about further improvements of the following code, but nothing too advanced, please.

The program is meant to work the following way:

1. A user inputs a color array like this one: `["blue", "green"]`
2. The code checks if those words are valid inputs (they should be found in a reference array of COLORS). This is done with `catchInvalid` function
3. If they are valid inputs, and so they are found in COLORS array, it gets the index of it. This is done in the `decodedValue` function

**Example1:**

```
COLORS= ["blue", "yellow", "red"]
User input: userColors=["yellow"]
returns index of yellow in COLORS i.e 1.
```

**Example2:**

```
COLORS= ["blue", "yellow", "red"]
User input: userColors=["yellow", "red"]
returns index 12 (index of yellow in colors*10 + index of red in colors (2)).
```

That's all. It's now working fine, but I wonder if you'd give any suggestions for improving the code.

```
    const COLORS = ["black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "grey", "white"];
 //this will be the reference array
    const catchInvalid = (color, COLORS) =>{
    //checks if color is in COLORS (which is COLORS)
            if(COLORS.indexOf(color)==-1){
                    return `not a ${color} in ${COLORS}`
            }
            else { }
    }
    
    const decodedValue = (colorArray) => {
            //if previous 'color' is in the reference array, get the index of the color in COLORS.
    let CODES=[];
    
    if (colorArray.length==0){
            return "Input a color value"
            }
    else if (colorArray.length==1){
            catchInvalid(colorArray[0], COLORS)
            return COLORS.indexOf(colorArray[0])
            }
    else {
    for(let i=0; i<2;i++){
            //only for the first 2 items in the array.
            catchInvalid(colorArray[i], COLORS)
            CODES.push(COLORS.indexOf(colorArray[i]))
            }
                                                                                                            return CODES[0]*10 + CODES[1];
        }
}

console.log(decodedValue(["blue"]), decodedValue(["nothing"]), decodedValue(["blue", "green"]))
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview

Comment: thx again :-) @konijn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a short review, considering you are a beginner;

- keep your variables in lowerCamelCase so

  - COLORS -> colors
  - CODES -> codes
- on the whole, avoid to have data type in the variable name

  - colorArray -> colors
- your commenting is quite good
- Your indenting is inconsistent, it easier to read your code when code is properly indented
- `catchInvalid` probably should return a boolean
- I would have called `catchInvalid` -> `isInvalidColor` it gives more detail
- `catchInvalid` should either use the global, or know the colors locally
- I would use `COLORS.includes()` over `COLORS.indexOf`
- There is way to calculate the return code without making a distinction between 1 or 2 elements

Per the comment, a bit more explicit

```
    function decodeColorValues(colors){
      //These are all the possible colors
      const knownColors = ["black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "grey", "white"];        

      //Functions should return a consistent datatypes, so I return -1 instead of a message
      //If the caller did not provide an aray but say "orange", then this will return -1 as well
      if(!colors.length){
        return -1;
      }
      
      //Filter out unknown colors
      colors = colors.filter(color => knownColors.includes(color));

      //If all colors were unknown then return -1
      //You could change this so that if 1 color is unknown it returns -1
      if(!colors.length){
        return -1;
      }      
      
      //We only deal with the first 2 entries (why?)
      colors = colors.slice(0,2);
      let value=0;
      
      //Abuse the fact that 10 times zero is still zero
      for(const color of colors){
        value = value * 10 + knownColors.indexOf(color);
      }
       
      return value;
    }


    console.log(decodeColorValues(["blue"]),
                decodeColorValues(["nothing"]),
                decodeColorValues(["blue", "green"]),
                decodeColorValues(["blue", "nothing"])
           );
```

Comment: I agree with everything you've stated here, but I don't agree with stating to a newcomer (or anyone, ever, in fact) that something _should_ be done _this_ way, simply _because I said so_. This doesn't help the person understand what makes one way of doing something better than another, and learning effectively only comes through understanding. I'll pre-empt a possible response that some would cite _"good coding practice"_ as the reason, which is not a reason, but a name given to a collection of guidelines that often don't come with an explanation.

Comment: @CJK You must be new to CodeReview, welcome!

Comment: Would you be more explicit in the last bullet point, please?

Comment: @misternobody Done!